# What is the quantifier complexity of the function sending an ordinal to the power set iterated that many times?

Tags: logic, set-theory

One use of the Axiom Schema of Replacement in ZFC is that it allows one to prove that for a set $X$ and a limit ordinal $\alpha$, the transfinitely iterated powerset $P^\alpha(X)$ exists (for a successor ordinal $\beta+1$, one only needs $P^\beta(X)$ to exist beforehand). Sometimes people consider restricted versions of Replacement with restricted complexity on the description of the function to which it is being applied. I was wondering what the quantifier complexity of the statement that Replacement is then applied to in order to get $P^\alpha(X)$. This would then put a floor on how low complexity Replacement instances can be before iterated powerset no longer becomes available.

Answer (score 3):

It looks $\Sigma_2$ to me: we have $y=\mathcal{P}^\alpha(x)$ iff there is a certain sequence of length $\alpha+1$ with first term $x$, last term $y$ and satisfying a certain $\Pi_1$ property (namely that limit terms are the unions of prior terms and successor terms are the powersets of their predecessor terms). So $\mathsf{KP+\Sigma_2Rep+Pow}$ proves the existence of ordinal iterates of the powerset operation.

This isn't as fine-grained as one might hope, though - $\Sigma_2$-$\mathsf{Rep}$ lets us do a lot more than just iterate the particular $\Pi_1$ powerset function, and so seems like overkill. If memory serves, a theory of intermediate strength which shows up a lot here is $\mathsf{KP^{Pow}}$ (maybe $\mathsf{KP^\mathcal{P}}$?). This is the analogue of $\mathsf{KP}$ in the language $\{\in,\mathcal{P}\}$: basically, the powerset operation is taken as primitive here, and we are given $\Delta_1$ separation and $\Sigma_1$ replacement *for formulas involving it*. This is intermediate between $\mathsf{KP}$ and $\mathsf{KP+\Sigma_2Rep+Pow}$ and, I believe, incomparable with $\mathsf{KP+\Sigma_2Rep}$.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, that's interesting.

Comment: @theHigherGeometer Incidentally, Adrian Mathias has a number of papers on systems in this general vicinity - see [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/scdlistB.html).

Comment: Thanks Noah, but I'm more interested in the context of ZFC.

Comment: @theHigherGeometer I'm not sure what you mean. Mathias' papers are on subsystems of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, just like $\mathsf{KP}+\Sigma_2\mathsf{Rep}$ or $\mathsf{KP^{Pow}}$ above. Aren't you asking about subsystems of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? (Note that Mathias identifies set theories of MacLane and Bourbaki with corresponding $\mathsf{ZFC}$-fragments.)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I wasn't thinking in terms of $KP \subset ZFC$. In that case, I accept the pointer much more humbly (and I confess I didn't click through, since I think I had looked at some of that work a few months back, as assumed I remembered it accurately)